# Nested CASE WHEN Formula(text) in Saved Search Results in NetSuite

Tags: case, netsuite, resultset, case-when, saved-searches

I have two fields `_courier` and `_trackingnumber`.
I would like to create in results nested CASE WHEN formula (text) under the following conditions:

1. the courier is = 'NAME'
   and
2. if the `_trackingnumber` of this courier does not start with `0` then add `00` else add `_trackingnumber` `&`

I have tried this CASE WHEN option and I realize that AND  function does not exist in Functions list in Netsuite

```
CASE WHEN {_courier} = 'NAME' AND ({_trackingnumber},'0'THEN ('00' || {_trackingnumber}) ELSE ('&' || {_trackingnumber}) END
```

And I got this error message:

> I got this error: **ERROR: Invalid Expression**

Can you please advise how to fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
CASE WHEN {_courier} = 'NAME' AND SUBSTR({_trackingnumber},1,1) <> '0' THEN ('00' || {_trackingnumber}) ELSE ('&' || {_trackingnumber}) END
```